# Delphi: Should allocated elements of array of PChar be freed manually?

Tags: delphi, freepascal

Consider the following code:

```
procedure Test;
var
  MyPCharArray: array of PChar;

begin
  SetLength(MyPCharArray, 3);

  GetMem(MyPCharArray[0], 5);
  GetMem(MyPCharArray[1], 5);
  GetMem(MyPCharArray[2], 5);

  StrCopy(MyPCharArray[0], 'test');
  StrCopy(MyPCharArray[1], 'abcd');
  StrCopy(MyPCharArray[2], '1234');

  // Are these necessary?
  FreeMem(MyPCharArray[0], 5);
  FreeMem(MyPCharArray[1], 5);
  FreeMem(MyPCharArray[2], 5);
end;
```

Should the allocated elements be freed manually, or the compiler will free the array elements automatically when `MyPCharArray` goes out of scope?

Comment: each call to GetMem must have a FreeMem counterpart, so to Answer your question : Yes

Comment: If FreePascal has something like ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutDown := true (Delphi) you can test for mem leaks yourself.

Comment: @Jan_Doggen, +1, even in Delphi, I'm not aware there is `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutDown`, thanks. :-)

Comment: @Astaroth: [ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutDown](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown) is a feature of [FastMM](http://fastmm.sourceforge.net), which Delphi has used for its memory manager for the past several years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed each of your calls to GetMem must be matched with a call to FreeMem.

I'm not sure why you have this array. It's not a type that I'd expect to see in pure Pascal code. So my guess is that you are passing the PChar array to some external library. In which case I'd declare an array of string as well as the array of PChar. And then make each PChar element by using PChar(...) on the corresponding element of the string array. Then you can avoid the StrCopy, GetMem and FreeMem.

```
procedure CallLib(const str: array of string);
var
  i: Integer;
  parr: array of PChar;
begin
  SetLength(parr, Length(str));
  for i := 0 to high(parr) do
    parr[i] := PChar(str[i]);
  // call library now
end;
```

Comment: @David_Heffernan, I'm creating a function that fills an `array of PChar` with command-line arguments like `argv[]` in C. I do this because the parsing strategy of `ParamStr()` not compatible with Microsoft C specification. Actually, the output variable is a `PPChar` (to be compatible with the FPC `argv` global variable), but inside the function, I put encountered command-line arguments in an `array of PChar`. Thanks for the answer as well as the tricks to avoid `StrCopy()`, `GetMem()`, and `Freemem()`.

Comment: OK, to make it easier, I will try to put encountered command-line arguments in an `array of string` and makes the output variable (`PPChar`) points to the array at the end of the function.

Comment: You have to create two arrays as per my answer. Because an empty string is a null pointer which is not how empty string is represented in PChar, aka C string.

Comment: Since the C `argv[argc]` is `#0`, I think setting the last element of `array of string` to `#0` is enough so that it points to the terminating null character instead of `nil`. What do you think?